# Nav underline maintain after click and under logo

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, angular

[Check out this js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7zs4s6ps/)

I have successfully added the underline to the nav when the user hovers over a link.

When the user clicks on a link it stays UNTIL they click on another portion of the screen then it disappears.

How do I get it to maintain the underline as long as the user is on the page?

Also there is button on the left side nav which is a link to the home page. However the underline functionality does not apply to this despite my attempts. Any ideas?

```
.navbar-brand img {
  height:33px;
  width: auto;
}

.navbar {
  line-height: 33px;
}

button {
    background-color:rgb(255, 102, 0);;
}
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav > li > a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav > li > a:focus, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
    color: rgb(255, 102, 0);;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(255, 102, 0);
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-nav > button.home:hover, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav >  button.home:focus, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav > .active > button.home, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
    color: rgb(255, 102, 0);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(255, 102, 0);
}
```

HTML

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md fixed-top navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" routerLink="/" routerLinkActive="active">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x30" alt="" />
  </a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler home" (click)="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault" [collapse]="isCollapsed">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/services" routerLinkActive="active">Products</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/case-studies" routerLinkActive="active">Testimonials</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/about" routerLinkActive="active">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/blog" routerLinkActive="active">Blog</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
       <a class="nav-link button" routerLink="/intouch" routerLinkActive="active"><button class="btn btn-outline-primary my-2 my-sm-0">Contact</button></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: You are required to post a complete example of the problem markup here, not a third party site that can change or disappear helping no one in the future: [mcve]

Comment: got it one moment....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the hover state to persist after the link is clicked on, simply use jQuery (you can also use native JS, but since Bootstrap requires jQuery we can simply use it) to bind click event listeners to:

- the `<a>` element in your navigation so that it adds a class, say `active`, to the link, and prevent the click event from bubbling up to the document
- the document object in your DOM so that it removes all `active` class from your navigation links

Your JS logic will look something like this:

```
$('.navbar-nav a').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).addClass('active');
});

$(document).click(function() {
    $('.navbar-nav a').removeClass('active');
});
```

If you also want to ensure that only a **single** element maintains this active state, you will have to remove the class from other anchor elements in your first click event handler, i.e.:

```
$('.navbar-nav a').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('.navbar-nav a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

To top that off, simply add a new `a.active` selector to your list:

```
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav > li > a:focus,
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus,
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav > li > a.active {
    color: rgb(255, 102, 0);;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(255, 102, 0);
}
```

See proof-of-concept example:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.navbar-nav a').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('.navbar-nav a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });

  $(document).click(function() {
    $('.navbar-nav a').removeClass('active');
  });

});
```

```css
.navbar-brand img {
  height: 33px;
  width: auto;
}

.navbar {
  line-height: 33px;
}

.footer {
  padding: 25px;
}

button {
  background-color: rgb(255, 102, 0);
  ;
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-nav>li>a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav>li>a:focus,
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav>.active>a,
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus,
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav>li>a.active {
  color: rgb(255, 102, 0);
  ;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(255, 102, 0);
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-nav>button.home:hover,
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav>button.home:focus,
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav>.active>button.home,
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
  color: rgb(255, 102, 0);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(255, 102, 0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md fixed-top navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" routerLink="/" routerLinkActive="active">
    <img class="vp-image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x30" alt="Dev" />
  </a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler home" (click)="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault" [collapse]="isCollapsed">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/services" routerLinkActive="active">Services</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/case-studies" routerLinkActive="active">Case Studies</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/about" routerLinkActive="active">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/blog" routerLinkActive="active">Blog</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <a class="nav-link button" routerLink="/intouch" routerLinkActive="active"><button class="btn btn-outline-primary my-2 my-sm-0">Contact</button></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: thanks for the input @Terry. The remove class does not seem to work. Any input on how to get the underline to apply to the button on left hand side?

Comment: @RyeGuy What do you mean by it does not seem to work?

Comment: Your snippet maintains underline on click but does not remove the previous underline after you click another li (Viewing in a safari browser)

Comment: @RyeGuy Okay, that wasn't clear in your question. Updated my answer.